# $(a,b,c) \in [0;1]$ then : $a(1-b) \leq \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: inequality

How can one show that if $(a,b,c) \in [0;1]$ then :

$a(1-b) \leq \frac{1}{4}$

Or

$b(1-c) \leq \frac{1}{4}$

Or

$c(1-a) \leq \frac{1}{4}$

To show that $x(1-x) \leq \frac{1}{4}$
For real x is simple

$-x^2+x-\frac{1}{4} \leq 0$

Im stuck to show something ( P or Q or R)

Comment: By AM-GM: $$\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{a(1-b)} \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc} (a+1-b) = \dfrac{3}{2}$$ so not all three can be greater than $\dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: @r9m can you please explain more . This would be an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$x (1-x) = \frac 14 - (x - \frac 12)^2 \le \frac 14$ holds for
all $x \in \mathbb R$. (Alternatively, use the GM-AM inequality,
or visualize $y = x(1-x)$ as a parabola with vertex at $(\frac 12, \frac 14)$.)

Then from
$$
 a(1-b) \cdot b (1-c) \cdot c (1-a) = a(1-a) \cdot b (1-b) \cdot c (1-c)
\le \frac 14 \cdot \frac 14 \cdot \frac 14
$$
it follows that at least one of the factors on the left must be $\le 1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: show the sum $a(1-b) + b(1-c) + c(1-a) \leq 3/4$.